# How to clean the resources in case android app crashed or manually killed?

Tags: android

In android app, I've been saving data in an external directory during the application run. After performing some operations I've been deleting the data so this case has no issue, but I want data to be deleted in case either app get crashed or manually killed by the user. What would be the more appropriate & standardized way to handle this case?

Comment: in case of crash, you can set a global custom unhandled exception handler, and clear the data before crashing your app. In case of force stop you can do nothing, as the app is stopped directly without ability to run any other piece of code

Comment: how about clearing your previous data if there is any before starting the app again. this should be easy.

Answer (score 2):

For force kill I am not sure but in case of crash you can delete the data as follows:

create a class used to handle `unCaughtException`

```
 public class MyExceptionHandler implements
            java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        private final Context myContext;
        private final Class<?> myActivityClass;

        public MyExceptionHandler(Context context, Class<?> c) {

            myContext = context;
            myActivityClass = c;
        }

        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {

            //delete your data
        }
    }
```

and in every Activity create an Object of this class and set it as the `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(this,
            YourCurrentActivity.class));
```

Answer (score -2):

Place the delete code in below method:

```
public void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy(); }
```

Comment: `onDestroy()` won't get triggered in case of crash !